# Found Screenshots of my work in my pc

Tags: arch-linux, security, gnome, screenshot

this could be a totally naive question but i can't figure out how it happened.

In a c++/python project i wrote, i suddenly found two files:
"np".
"sys".
The file command says:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0
%%Creator: (ImageMagick)
%%Title: (np)
%%CreationDate: (2017-04-28T00:27:01+02:00)
```

Opening them with evince shows me a file in which the pages are screenshots of my work.

[image: np]
[image: sys]
I use ArchLinux with i3wm and vim+SublimeCodeText+Vundle for coding.
Is this a "feature" i used without realizing it or someone wanted to left me a message?

EDIT: What i am asking is: do you've heard of some feature of i3wm\gnome that allow you to take screenshots and put them sequentially in a pdf like the images i showed? Is it possible i used this feature without being aware of it, for example with a shortcut?

Comment: Only downvotes without comments. Some explanation?

Comment: Type `history` on the terminal , you will found `imoprt  np` and `import sys` , maybe your are type it by mistake.

Comment: Whooo, you rock. Never heard of such command, mistery solved, thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAD3R solved this for me.

I typed by mistake in the console "import sys" where `import` is a tool for capturing X windows and store them in a pdf file.